# MS Access SQL - Left Join a table that only has unique matches

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using an example database I got through DBeaver. It contains a table called Artists and a table called Albums. Some artists have no albums, some have one and some have many.

What I'm trying to achieve is a left join to show all artists but only display the album name of the artists who only have one album.

The following works using DBeaver but doesn't work if executed directly from MS Access (which i need to be able to do):

```
SELECT
ar.AName,
al.title
FROM
Artist ar
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    al.*
FROM
    album al
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        artistid,
        COUNT( artistid ) artistCount
    FROM
        album
    GROUP BY
        artistid ) alc ON
    alc.artistid = al.artistid
    AND alc.artistcount = 1 ) al ON
al.artistid = ar.artistid
ORDER BY
ar.aname
```

Tables have the following columns:

```
Artist
    ArtistID (Key)
    Name

Album
    AlbumID (Key)
    Title
    ArtistID
```

Many thanks in advance. I can't find an answer to this anywhere. I understand the version of SQL used in MS Access isn't the same as found in various other variants.

Cheers

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I have managed to produce the results I was expecting using SQL in MS Access (will need to test to ensure its 100%).

I used the following:

```
SELECT
    ar.AName,
    al.title
FROM
    Artist ar
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        al.*
    FROM
        album al,
        (
        SELECT
            al1.artistid,
            COUNT( al1.artistid ) AS al1Count
        FROM
            album al1
        GROUP BY
            al1.artistid ) al1
    WHERE
        al.artistID = al1.artistid
        AND al1.al1count = 1 ) al ON
    al.artistid = ar.artistid
ORDER BY
    ar.aname
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT a.ArtistID, a.Name, al.Title
FROM Artist a LEFT JOIN
     Album al
     ON al.ArtistID = a.ArtistID AND 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM Album al1 
                    WHERE al1.ArtistID = al.ArtistID AND a1l.AlbumID <> al.AlbumID
                   );
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. This works fine through DBeaver but not directly in MS Access. It's throwing the error 'Syntax error in query expression ''.'

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `left join`.  If an artist has exactly *one* album, then a regular `join` will work.  The key is aggregation:

```
select ar.aname, max(al.title) as title
from artist as ar inner join
     album as al
     on ar.artistid = al.artistid
group by ar.artistid, ar.aname  -- I supposed two artists could have the same name
having count(*) = 1;
```

The key idea is that if there is only one album, then `max(al.title)` returns that album's name.

EDIT: (based on comment)

```
select ar.aname,
       switch(al.artistid is null, "No album"
              count(*) = 1, max(al.title),
              1=1, "> 1"
             ) as album_title
from artist as ar left join
     album as al
     on ar.artistid = al.artistid
group by ar.artistid, ar.aname;
```

Comment: . . .  No he wants to display all artist name.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I still want to display the artist names with either no albums or more than one albums but only display the actual album name if they only have one.

Comment: @MackScania . . . The query is easily adjusted to handle this.